# Can't bake normals from high poly mesh to low poly mesh correctly?

Tags: normal-map

No matter what I do, the normal map never comes out right.  There's always weird coloring (bright orange, greens, pinks) or artifacting.  Any help on how to actually bake it would be amazing, I've been struggling with baking normals for a long time

Here's the blend file: [image]

Comment: If you increase the Ray Distance a bit it seems ok

Comment: You have artefacts (bad colors) because some surfaces of the high-poly go out of the surfaces of the low-poly. You need to increase the Ray Distance value, i.e. increase the distance that is scanned. If the distance is too high it might also create artefacts because the ray might hit another surface on its path, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Sorry. could you walk me through this?  Even though I set it to 1m, Mine always come out like this:https://imgur.com/a/3H8rWrM

Comment: yes, that seems good, all these colors are part of the normal spectrum of a correct normal map

Comment: Ah really?  Why does it mesh up my low poly mesh?  Is it an issue with the mesh?

Comment: Specifically I mean with this, how do I make the meshes as close to eachother as possible: https://imgur.com/a/TiNBFsh

Comment: yes you're right there's a problem with the side of his head...

Comment: so I guess you need to paint the normal map (use the pipet to catch the purple) so that you won't see these bad colors